# how to loop through the xml using linq in c#?

Tags: linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pricebooks>
    <pricebook>
        <header pricebook-id="Indian Rupees">
            <currency>INR</currency>
            <display-name xml:lang="x-default">Indian Rupees</display-name>
            <description xml:lang="x-default">Indian Rupees</description>
            <online-flag>true</online-flag>
        </header>

        <price-tables>
            <price-table product-id="0100014">
                <amount quantity="1">12000.00</amount>
                <amount quantity="3">30000.00</amount>
                <price-info>testpriceinfo</price-info>
            </price-table>

            <price-table product-id="LST">
                <amount quantity="1">555.00</amount>
            </price-table>
        </price-tables>
    </pricebook>
</pricebooks>
```

How to loop through the above xml using linq?
I just want to loop through and print values in the console.
Following fields i want to display in console.

1. pricebook_id
2. currency
3. display-name
4. description
5. onlineflag
6. product_id
7. quantity

Comment: Read about Linq to XML, there are millions of articles about it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a dirty example, no null value checking, no missing element assumed. The purpose is only to show how to loop through and get each element of interest, just as you ask in the question :

```
var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<pricebooks>
    <pricebook>
        <header pricebook-id=""Indian Rupees"">
            <currency>INR</currency>
            <display-name xml:lang=""x-default"">Indian Rupees</display-name>
            <description xml:lang=""x-default"">Indian Rupees</description>
            <online-flag>true</online-flag>
        </header>

        <price-tables>
            <price-table product-id=""0100014"">
                <amount quantity=""1"">12000.00</amount>
                <amount quantity=""3"">30000.00</amount>
                <price-info>testpriceinfo</price-info>
            </price-table>

            <price-table product-id=""LST"">
                <amount quantity=""1"">555.00</amount>
            </price-table>
  </price-tables>
    </pricebook>
</pricebooks>";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (var pricebook in doc.Descendants("pricebook"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(pricebook.Element("header").Attribute("pricebook-id").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(pricebook.Element("header").Element("currency").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(pricebook.Element("header").Element("display-name").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(pricebook.Element("header").Element("description").Value);
    Console.WriteLine(pricebook.Element("header").Element("online-flag").Value);
    foreach (var priceTable in pricebook.Descendants("price-table"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(priceTable.Attribute("product-id").Value);
        foreach (var amount in priceTable.Elements("amount"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(amount.Attribute("quantity").Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any question regarding this solution, or it worked fine for you?

Comment: sorry it's working fine but if you see an xml,the pricetable has 2 account element.but it's printing only one time.any idea?

Comment: I missed that part, the code before will only print quantity of the first amount element if multiple amount exist. I updated the answer to print from all amount elements, check it out